# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php

i would like to send my data from mssql via php to my chart. For this i'm using `$.get` function to receive data from mssql.
but i'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` obviously i can't access an object.

my php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['employeesChart'])) {
    getemployeesChart($conn);
}

function getemployeesChart($conn) {
  $sql ="SELECT * FROM employee;
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
  $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
  $isAtWork = $row['Work'];
  $isAtHome = $row['Home'];
  $data = array('isAtWork' => $isAtWork, 'isAtHome' => $isAtHome);
  echo json_encode($data)
}
```

and my javascript code:

```
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Home",
        "Work",
        "Break"
    ],
    datasets: [{
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: ["#FF6384","#36A2EB","#FFCE56"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384","#36A2EB","#FFCE56"]
    }]
};

$.get("employees.inc.php?employeesChart", function(data){
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    var test = data.datasets[0].data.push(result[0],result[1]);
    myDoughnutChart.update();
});

// Doughnut Chart
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            }
        }
});
```

i don't understand why do i get an error. When i test it with `console.log(result)` im getting two integers but the code sample make `data.datasets[0].data.push(result[0],result[1])` an error

Comment: Edit your question, show result output and mention what you want from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: did you really want `data.datasets[0]`? Or should it be `result.datasets[0]`

Comment: yes i just want to push my two values from $.parseJSON(data)